# .NetCore Web API: I got error 403 for put and delete in hosting server

Tags: asp.net-core

I am getting `403` error when doing `PUT` and `DELETE` but `GET` and `POST` are fine.

Here is my `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" 
           path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT" 
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In my local machine it works fine, but not in the hosting server. I have contacted the server support. They said that they already allow the `PUT` and `DELETE` verbs from their server.

[image]

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\XXXXXXXXXXX.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Nothing has changed, the error still persist.

Comment: @AlvinStefanus I updated my answer.try this.```runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests``` make this true.

Comment: Hello, I tried it, but the problem still persist, nothing is changed. I tried to contact the support one more time. I tried to publish my app in Cloud Run and Heroku, both of them are fine maybe because it was wrapped in Docker container. This server is IIS server, I do not use Docker. I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: @AlvinStefanus now that's cleared your code is ok. I think you have to contact the hosting provider. They should be made some settings.

Comment: I thought so, thanks anyway for your time.